# SQL query return what's NOT in table

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: find missing IDs in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table)
>   [getting values which dont exist in mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114980/getting-values-which-dont-exist-in-mysql-table)

Just wondering, is it possible to have a query that somehow tells you the values it did not find in a table?

So if I had a query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` and only 2,3,6,7,9 was returned. I wouldd like to know that 1,4,5,8 were not found.

It will be a little hard to do a manual comparision, because this is going to be run over apx 2,000+ rows in a table *(the id's are going to be provided via a csv file which can be copied into the query)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: While that question is about missing values from a range, the result is the same -> only difference is you have an allready known list of id's you need to provide to the temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably silly, but what about creating a [temporary table](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) containing all your IDs from which you'll substract the result of your SELECT query ?

Comment: Substracting sounds like something inefficient. I'd say `LEFT JOIN` the table.

Comment: A temporary table and a JOIN to show values in table B that are not in table A, giving me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but in theory:

```
Table 1:
+----+-----+
| id | num |
+----+-----+

Table 2:
+----+
| id |
+----+
```

Table 1 contains the data you're looking for (and `num` is any field containing any data)
Table 2 contains the IDs from the CSV

```
SQL:
SELECT COUNT(`Table1`.`num`) AS `count`
FROM `Table1`
LEFT JOIN `Table2` ON `Table1`.`id` = `Table2`.`id`
WHERE `count` = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, open your csv file, replace all comma's with " union select " put select in front of that line and use it as the first line of the query at the bottom query.

So 1,2,3 becomes

Select 1 union select 2 union select 3

Use this in the query below

```
    Select 1 union select 2 union select x -- replace this line with the line generated from your csv
    Except
    (
     Select id from mytable
    )
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support EXCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`SELECT *` 
   `FROM (select 1 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 2 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 3 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 4 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 5 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 6 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 7 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 8 as f` 
               `UNION` 
               `SELECT 9 ) as s1` 
 `WHERE f NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable);`